# OData Vdm Generator returns an error on a particular EDMX file

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to generate classes using the odata-generator-cli-3.52.0 on the EDMX file that you can download from the following API Hub link: https://api.sap.com/api/ProjectServiceV2/overview. The command I'm using is the following: `java -jar odata-generator-cli-3.52.0.jar -b "/"`, however, I'm receiving this error (and I get the same when using the generato as a Maven Plugin):

```
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGenerator - Generating EVERYTHING with parameters:
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGenerator -   Input directory:                /Users/i045523/Temp/simmaco/input
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGenerator -   Output directory:               /Users/i045523/Temp/simmaco/target
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGenerator -   Delete output directory:        false
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGenerator -   Overwrite files:                false
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGenerator -   Package name:                   com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGenerator -   Default base path:              /
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGenerator -   Service name mapping file:      /Users/i045523/Temp/simmaco/serviceNameMappings.properties
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGenerator -   Naming strategy class:          com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.utility.S4HanaNamingStrategy
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGenerator -   Name source (default strategy): LABEL
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGenerator -   Annotation strategy class:      com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.annotation.DefaultAnnotationStrategy
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGenerator -   Pattern for excluded files:     
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGenerator -   Link to API Business Hub:       false
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGenerator -   Fail on Warning:                false
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGenerator -   Entity sets to process:         <all>
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGenerator -   Function imports to process:    <all>
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.ODataToVdmGenerator - Loading OData service ProjectServiceV2
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.ODataToVdmGenerator - Reading metadata file: /Users/i045523/Temp/simmaco/input/ProjectServiceV2.edmx
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.ODataToVdmGenerator - Reading swagger file:  null
Warning: validation was turned on but an org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler was not set, which is probably not what is desired.  Parser will use a default ErrorHandler to print the first 0  errors.  Please call the setErrorHandler method to fix this.
Error: URI=file:/Users/i045523/Temp/simmaco/input/ProjectServiceV2.edmx Line=2: Document root element "edmx:Edmx", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
Error: URI=file:/Users/i045523/Temp/simmaco/input/ProjectServiceV2.edmx Line=2: Document is invalid: no grammar found.
Warning: validation was turned on but an org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler was not set, which is probably not what is desired.  Parser will use a default ErrorHandler to print the first 0  errors.  Please call the setErrorHandler method to fix this.
Error: URI=file:/Users/i045523/Temp/simmaco/input/ProjectServiceV2.edmx Line=2: Document root element "edmx:Edmx", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
Error: URI=file:/Users/i045523/Temp/simmaco/input/ProjectServiceV2.edmx Line=2: Document is invalid: no grammar found.
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.ODataToVdmGenerator -   Title: ProjectServiceV2
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.ODataToVdmGenerator -   Raw URL: /service.ProjectServiceV1
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.ODataToVdmGenerator -   Java Package Name: projectservicev2
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.ODataToVdmGenerator -   Java Class Name: ProjectServiceV2
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.ODataToVdmGenerator - Processing 1 OData service...
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.ODataToVdmGenerator - Processing OData service 'ProjectServiceV2' at /service.ProjectServiceV1
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.NamespaceClassGenerator -   Found entity type GroupMemberships from set GroupMemberships
[main] WARN com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.ODataToVdmGenerator - Error in file ProjectServiceV2; unable to generate all VDM classes.
com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.ODataGeneratorReadException: org.apache.olingo.odata2.api.edm.EdmException: An exception occurred.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.EdmService$TypedAdapter.getType(EdmService.java:322)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.NamespaceClassGenerator.processNavigationProperties(NamespaceClassGenerator.java:1187)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.NamespaceClassGenerator.processEntitySet(NamespaceClassGenerator.java:924)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.EntitySetProcessor.processEntitySets(EntitySetProcessor.java:78)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.CodeModelClassGenerator.processService(CodeModelClassGenerator.java:123)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.ODataToVdmGenerator.createCodeModelForServices(ODataToVdmGenerator.java:129)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.ODataToVdmGenerator.generate(ODataToVdmGenerator.java:92)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGenerator.execute(DataModelGenerator.java:662)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGeneratorCli.run(DataModelGeneratorCli.java:216)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGeneratorCli.main(DataModelGeneratorCli.java:198)
Caused by: org.apache.olingo.odata2.api.edm.EdmException: An exception occurred.
    at org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.edm.provider.EdmAssociationEndImplProv.getEntityType(EdmAssociationEndImplProv.java:51)
    at org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.edm.provider.EdmNavigationPropertyImplProv.getType(EdmNavigationPropertyImplProv.java:44)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.EdmService$TypedAdapter.getType(EdmService.java:319)
    ... 9 more
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.ODataToVdmGenerator - Generating Java classes to /Users/i045523/Temp/simmaco/target
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGeneratorCli - ------------------------------------------------------------
[main] WARN com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGeneratorCli -  Generator SUCCEEDED but had the following 1 warning messages:
[main] WARN com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGeneratorCli - Error in file ProjectServiceV2; unable to generate all VDM classes.
[main] INFO com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.generator.DataModelGeneratorCli - ------------------------------------------------------------
```

Do you know where is the problem with this file?
Regards,
Simmaco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the EDMX specification file. For the Navigation property `toUser` an Entity type that is not defined is referenced i.e, `Users`.

```java
<NavigationProperty Name="toUser" Relationship="service.ProjectServiceV1.GroupMemberships_toUser" FromRole="GroupMemberships" ToRole="Users"/>
```

Removing this property and it's associated `Association` and `AssociationSet` from the EDMX file results in a successful VDM generation.

Comment: I have also reached out to the service owners to correct the faulty specification file. I will update the issue once the specification file is updated and is available in SAP API Business Hub.